# Download tarball with `wget` only if more recently modified than local extracted content

Tags: wget

There is a .tgz archive on a remote server. I only want to download this file if it is more recent than the local copy of its *contents* that I have. If I kept the old copy of the .tgz around, I could use `wget -N`. But instead, I only keep the extracted contents. How can I use the equivalent of `wget -N` while keeping only a copy of the contents? The solution should be as cross-platform as possible.

One thing I tried was:

- storing the extracted content in a unique directory
- setting access/modified timestamps on the directory to be the same as that of the tarball
- when checking for a new version, `touch -r <directory> <tarball>` to create a fake version of the target file with the appropriate timestamps
- `wget -N`

But this failed because `wget -N` checks both the file size and the timestamps, and my fake tarball doesn't have the right size.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don’t want to keep the old tarball? That’s really the easiest and most foolproof method.

On Linux, you could use `dd` to create a file of the right size pretty easily and use `touch` to fix the time stamp.

---

Save the time stamp and size before you delete the tarball:

```
wc -c tar.tgz | awk ‘{ print $1 }’ > ref_file
touch -r tar.tgz ref_file
```

Recreate dummy of right size:

```
dd of=tar.tgz seek=$(cat ref_file) count=0
touch -r ref_file tar.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with curl instead of wget?

`$ curl --time-cond <directory> --remote-time --output <tarball> <download_url>`

`--time-cond` can be either a time string or a filename.

`--remote-time` sets the time of the downloaded file to the same as the remote.